# Dynamically building a command pipe in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, command

I am writing a bash program that takes options.

For example : `./my_program -l 3 -a -s`

- `-l 3` will limit the output to three lines
- `-a` will select all my file
- `-s` will sort the output

For now, I could use two options at a time this way:

```
if [ $all == 1 ]
then
    if [ $sort == 1 ]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort
    else
        printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
    fi
fi
```

If `-a` option, I print the whole file, or, if `-a` option and `-s` option, I use the same command but i use `sort`.

With this solution, if I want to implement the `-l`, it would create a lot of "if" statements.

I first thought of creating a variable containing my command.

Example:

```
sort='sort'
limit='grep -m3'
```

and then write my command this way:

```
printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | $sort | $limit
```

But that is simply not working.

The fact is, I would like to write a basic command, and being able to add more to this one, depending of the options.

How can I do this properly without tons of "if" statements?

Comment: You could build a key value array , but honestly I don’t see why you would want to build dynamic inputs

Comment: FYI, using `==` in `[` is not guaranteed to work in all POSIX-compliant shells. It's more reliable to use `=` for string comparison, as it's required to work by [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), and correspondingly works even with minimal `/bin/sh` implementations, not just bash.

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe directly to an `if` statement. This will require a no-op filter like `cat`, though, in some places, so it is slightly less efficient in that regard.

```
printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' |
 if [ "$sort" = 1 ]; then sort; else cat; fi |
 if [ "$l" -gt 0 ]; then grep -m"$l"; else cat; fi
```

An `if` statement is itself a command, so it has its own sets of file descriptors that the enclosed commands inherit. The `if` statement itself doesn't *do* anything with those descriptors, so `sort` and `cat` both see the data they would if they hadn't been wrapped in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Great question with a tricky, not-so-obvious solution.

What you can do is chain together a couple of function calls. Those functions can examine the relevant flags and then either "do something" like call `sort` or "do nothing" and simply call `cat`. A plain `cat` call in a pipeline is essentially a no-op: it copies stdin to stdout unchanged.

```
maybe_sort() {
    if [[ $sort == 1 ]]; then
        sort
    else
        cat
    fi
}

maybe_limit() {
    if [[ -n $limit ]]; then
        head -n "$limit"
    else
        cat
    fi
}
```

To use these you'd then write:

```
printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | maybe_sort | maybe_limit
```

Comment: FYI, I took the liberty of adopting your functions in an answer to [Can I make a shell function in a pipeline conditionally disappear without using `cat`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023975/can-i-make-a-shell-function-in-as-a-pipeline-conditionally-disappear-without)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for solution without fixed order. Ended up with:

```sh
# assemble pipeline from sequence of arguments
# each argument interpreted as command to evaluate (e.g. spaces interpreted)
pipe_all() {
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        local current=$1
        shift
        eval "$current" | pipe_all "$@"
    else
        cat
    fi
}

filter_weapon() {
    grep '/Weapon/'
}

filters=()
filters+=(sort)
filters+=(uniq)
filters+=(filter_weapon)
filters+=("head -n $1")  # should be encoded as a single argument and be a valid command

pipe_all "${filters[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone. I'm replying a bit late. I didn't know I could use cat as a no-op, and that was the solution I sought.
So I simply initialized all my options with "cat" op. If the option is triggered correctly, I simply update the string with the good op.
Then, I just had to write one op line, with all options in it.

Thank you a lot.