# Can I make a shell function in as a pipeline conditionally "disappear", without using cat?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, cat

I have a bash script that produces some text from a pipe of commands. Based on a command line option I want to do some validation on the output. For a contrived example...

```
CHECK_OUTPUT=$1
...
check_output()
{
    if [[ "$CHECK_OUTPUT" != "--check" ]]; then
        # Don't check the output. Passthrough and return.
        cat
        return 0
    fi

    # Check each line exists in the fs root
    while read line; do
        if [[ ! -e "/$line" ]]; then
            echo "Error: /$line does not exist"
            return 1
        fi
        echo "$line"
    done
    return 0
}

ls /usr | grep '^b' | check_output
```

[EDIT] better example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539364/1888983

This is really useful, particularly if I have multiple functions that can becomes passthroughs. Yes, I could move the CHECK_OUTPUT conditional and create a pipe with or without check_output but I'd need to write lines for each combination for more functions. If there are better ways to dynamically build a pipe I'd like to know.

The problem is the "useless use of cat". Can this be avoided and make `check_output` like it wasn't in the pipe at all?

Comment: That's not a useless use of cat. This is exactly what `cat` with no arguments is good for.

Comment: BTW, at the risk of pulling my pedant hat down on my head until it's cutting off bloodflow... `$CHECK_OUTPUT` is not a great variable name; [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) that environment variable names containing only all-caps characters and underscores are reserved for use by the shell itself and other POSIX-specified utilities; because setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable (even without any explicit `export` being provided), this convention extends to regular shell variables as well.

Comment: @jozxyqk : One different approach is to initially set for each shell function in question an environment variable. For instance, if _check_output_ should really be executed, set `check_output_fn=check_output`, and if it is pass-thru, set `check_output_fn=cat`. Then invoke it as `.... |grep '^b' |$check_output_fn`.

Comment: @user1934428, ...the whole thing that distinguishes this question from [the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539364) is that the OP wants to have any noop stage *not happen at all*, instead of substituting `cat` there. Also, using variable names to store code in shell is [heavily frowned on](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Using varnames for code is IMO safe, if (1) I control exactly what goes in the variable, and (2) the 'code' consists of a single word, denoting an executable, without embedded spaces and other fancy syntax stuff. Since in the OPs case, the 'code' is just the name of a function, and he places the name of the function or system command in the variable, I don't see where this could be risky.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I don't see how he can get rid of _cat_ , if he wants to have the no-op command as part of a general pipeline. Even a _noop_ command written by himself must at least copy stdin to stdout.

Comment: @user1934428, re: "don't see how" -- see my answer, which _shows_ how. The answer is to inject the pipeline element only conditionally, so if the pipeline isn't needed, none is created in the first place, so there's no need for a program to copy stdin to stdout at all.

Comment: And yes, you're right, subject to the stated conditions putting a single word in a variable is safe; I still frown on it, because folks who don't know the caveats are liable to try to extend it beyond that safely limited set of conditions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I got it! great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this -- by making your function a wrapper that conditionally injects a pipeline element, instead of being an unconditional pipeline element itself. For example:

```
maybe_checked() {
  if [[ $CHECK_OUTPUT != "--check" ]]; then
    "$@" # just run our arguments as a command, as if we weren't here
  else
    # run our arguments in a process substitution, reading from stdout of same.
    # ...some changes from the original code:
    #   IFS= stops leading or trailing whitespace from being stripped
    #   read -r prevents backslashes from being processed
    local line # avoid modifying $line outside our function
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      [[ -e "/$line" ]] || { echo "Error: /$line does not exist" >&2; return 1; }
      printf '%s\n' "$line"  # see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803
    done < <("$@")
  fi
}

ls /usr | maybe_checked grep '^b'
```

Caveat of the above code: if the `pipefail` option is set, you'll want to check the exit status of the process substitution to have complete parity with the behavior that would otherwise be the case. In bash version 4.3 or later (IIRC), `$?` is modified by process substitutions to have the relevant PID, which can be `wait`ed for to retrieve exit status.

That said, this is also a use case wherein using `cat` is acceptable, and I'm saying this as a card-carying member of the UUOC crowd. :)

---

Adopting the examples from John Kugelman's answers on the linked question:

```
maybe_sort() {
    if (( sort )); then
        "$@" | sort
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

maybe_limit() {
    if [[ -n $limit ]]; then
        "$@" | head -n "$limit"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

printf '%s\n' "${haikus[@]}" | maybe_limit maybe_sort sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```